# Condition Formatting, changing the ranges colour depending on the total of that range

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to conditional format some cells so that if the added value of those cells = 0 it goes green and then a separate one if the sum does not equal 0. Currently, I am using a total cell to determine this (BALANCE LEVEL), but I want to eliminate the use of this and have the format rule to sum the values and determine the colour without the use of this cell.

Custom formula is

```
=SUM(AQ39:AQ48)=0
```

This to turn the column green

and then another rule with this formula

```
=SUM(AQ39:AQ48)<>0
```

This to turn the column red

I expected this to change the column green if the total of all the values in that column = 0, and red if the sum does not. It only changes some of the cells, even though the range I have applied it to is that whole column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear any existing CF from your range, fill it 'standard' red fill and  apply this CF formula rule with green fill:

```
=SUM(AQ$39:AQ$48)=0
```

Beware of floating point errors.